# Connect symlinked device to docker container

Tags: docker

I have a USB device plugged into the host, which (using udev rules) symlinks /dev/ttyZigbee and /dev shows my devices are present (and dmesg confirmed drivers loaded fine):

```
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 166,  1 Nov 22 11:49 /dev/ttyACM1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         15 Nov 22 11:49 /dev/ttyZigbee -> bus/usb/002/005
```

I create the container as follows:

```
docker run -d --init \
   -p 8090:8090 \
   -e TZ='America/Toronto' \
   -v /data/zigbee2mqtt/data:/app/data \
   -v /run/udev:/run/udev:ro \
   --name zigbee2mqtt \
   --device=/dev/ttyZigbee \
   docker.io/koenkk/zigbee2mqtt
```

but when the container start the log shows:

```
Zigbee2MQTT:error 2023-11-23 04:22:53: Error: Error while opening serialport 'Error: Error: No such file or directory, cannot open /dev/ttyZigbee'
```

Why is my device not passing through to the container, or why is it not openable in the container?  Is it symlinking / privilege / etc?

Comment: sooo does `--device=/dev/bus/usb/002/005` work?

Comment: I have not tried that since I assume that number may change on reboots - is that correct?  Numerous accepted answers on SO used the device name (not number) so I have avoided that.

Comment: `is that correct?` No idea. Does it work? `when the container start` Is the log from the process inside the container, or is it a log of docker demon? Does a `alpine` container works?